Looking for a movie where a woman in a bunker talks to a man who tries to get in
I don't know the name of this movie but I saw a trailer while watching TV.
By what I saw it looked like people locked themselves in a bunker to avoid chaos going on outisde, there's a window. A woman was talking to a guy who was trying to get in to the bunker, she then runs up to the door to the bunker there's a scratch on the plastic that says "HELP", after this she runs up the stairs, a man screams, "Don't open that door!", she opens it, there is explosions, and she's wearing a mask. End of trailer.

10 Cloverfield Lane?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_Cloverfield_Lane

After surviving a car accident, a woman, Michelle, wakes up in an underground cellar, where most of the film takes place. She fears she has been abducted by survivalist Howard Stambler, who tells her he saved her life, and that a worldwide chemical attack has left Earth's surface uninhabitable. Uncertain what to believe, she decides to escape, no matter what dangers she may face outside.




